# Redirect location after ajax call in a click event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, ejs

The code below is supposed to

1. Process the delete request when the delete `a` tag is select
2. redirect to the `/projects` webpage.

it seems like the redirect to `/projects` is occurring before the delete function gets a chance to run.

Is there a best practice that I'm missing here? or is there a better way to do this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#delete').click(function() {
    var settings = {
      url: `http://localhost:3000/projects/<%= project.id %>`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      timeout: 0,
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<form class="update-project" method="POST" action="/update-project">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">ID</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value="<%= project.id %>" disabled />
  </div>
  <a type="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/projects">Cancel</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Submit</button>
  <a id="delete" type="delete" class="btn btn-danger" href="/projects"> DELETE </a>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is the redirect?

Comment: The Cancel button links to `/project`. There's no `href` in the Delete button, so it should link back to the current URL by default.

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent linking to the `href`. Then you can assign to `window.location` in the `$.ajax` callback function.

Comment: You want to: first do the ajax request to perform the `delete` then in your callback (where you have the console.log) you should trigger the redirection with js. The way you have it now the redirect will always happen before the 'click' function gets executed.

Comment: I would not recommend an "a" tag for a delete action.  Also your form is confusing - it has a POST method.

Comment: @JoanAlbert thank you. That makes sense. However, when I put `window.location.replace('http://localhost:3000/projects/');` after `console.log()` it doesnt work. It does work when it is outside of the `done` function, but then I'm stuck with the same problem.

Comment: `$('#delete').click(function()` it should be `$('#delete').click(function(event)` and then place `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Also do the redirection inside `done` as said earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will try to answer using all the information the colleagues left in the comments.

We need to:

1 -  Get the click button.
2 -  Call `event.preventDefault()` to avoid refresh due to the `<form method="POST" action=...>`.
3 - Do the ajax request on the "click" event.
4 - In the ajax callback do the redirection.

Step by step:

1 - I will remove the `href="/projects"` from `<a id="delete" type="delete" class="btn btn-danger" href="/projects"> DELETE </a>`

2 - Add `event.preventDefault()` in the first line of the "click" callback.

3 - Add `window.location.replace('/projects')` in the first line of the ajax callback.

After all this it would look like:

```html
<form class="update-project" method="POST" action="/update-project">
  <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-default">ID</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id" aria-label="Sizing example input" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-default" value="<%= project.id %>" disabled />
  </div>
  <a type="cancel" class="btn btn-secondary" href="/projects">Cancel</a>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary float-right">Submit</button>
  <a id="delete" type="delete" class="btn btn-danger"> DELETE </a>
</form>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#delete').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var settings = {
      url: `http://localhost:3000/projects/${project.id}>`,
      method: 'DELETE',
      timeout: 0,
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function() {
      window.location.replace('/projects');
    });
  });
})
```

**Note:** I also want to add that the HTML structure doesn't make sense with what you want to do. You are creating an HTML form, but at the same time, you want to handle the form calls via JS instead of using the native HTML form you already have there. It should be refactored to get cleaner and less buggy-prone.

**Note 2:** You should not use `<a>` tags as buttons, buttons should be used as buttons because this is what they are :)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to be working on my end. I could have something else going on. The delete works, but I never successfully redirect to the `/projects` page.

Comment: Marking yours as the answer as it is correct, there was however the additional redirect issue in my routes

Answer (score 0):

Issue ended up being another part of my code on the server side. I needed to return the status code in the express js router.put via `return response.redirect(303, '/projects');`

```
const express = require('express');
const ProjectModel = require('../src/controller/projectController');
const router = express.Router();
const controller = new ProjectModel();

module.exports = (params) => {

  router.delete('/:id', async (request, response) => {
    await controller.deleteById(request.params);
    return response.redirect(303, '/projects');
  });

  return router;
}
```